# Is it possible to add a spring bean to ejb EmptyInterceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

In my application I have the following interceptor:

```
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
```

adding `@Component` on the top of the class is working but I am not able to add a service bean from my application since I want to execute some service logic. What I am doing is the following is:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

private final List<Class<?>> updates = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<Class<?>> creates = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<Class<?>> loads = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<Class<?>> deletes = new ArrayList<>();

private final TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();

private final PropertyRepository propertyRepository;

public AuditInterceptor(PropertyRepository propertyRepository) {
    this.propertyRepository = propertyRepository;
}
```

and it fails with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyPartnerRepository' defined in com.microservice.persistence.PropertyPartnerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Could not instantiate named strategy class [com.microservice.persistence.AuditInterceptor]
```

I want to know if there is a way to execute add a service bean in this interceptor so I can execute some service logic?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @Repository annotation on the PropertyRepository interface which you are trying to inject in AuditInterceptor class.

Comment: That is not working, EmptyInterceptor it's an ejb interceptor so saying to a repo that is a repository will not change anything at all